# How do I debug crashing application from inside docker and prevent it from terminating?

Tags: docker, windows-10, node.js

I need to debug an application that is crashing inside a docker, how do I achieve that the docker does not stop when the app crashes, allowing me to `-it` inside and try starting the app manually?

Comment: Thats…. Not how You should be doing it. Log your errors to stderr and review them when the container crashes.

Comment: @GregL I log the errors, but since I can't reproduce the error outside of container, I need to step over the code inside the docker. I may also need to modify files in the docker on the fly to understand what's wrong and how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, this is what I did:

First, know that **it is possible to *pause* the container** before it runs any command, such as `npm start`, etc. We can then **enter the docker container with terminal** and run any command by hand. Running the app like this won't exit and shut down the container on a critical error. We can even **mount local filesystem inside the docker** and run the app from there with the docker picking up changes live - **perfect for debugging!**

---

## Project layout

In my particular case, it was a NestJS app with two important folders

- `/src` - the app source code (development, `nest start --watch`)
- `/dist` - the output folder for built app (production)
  (`npm run build`(`nest build`), `npm run start:prod`(`node dist/src/main`))

The docker was then configured to copy the built `/dist` folder and relevant files to an `/app` folder which was used as `WORKDIR` from where the app was then launched.

Excerpt from `Dockerfile` (simplified a lot)

```bash
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm run build

COPY /app/tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json
COPY /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY /app/dist ./dist

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

With this clear, let's now look at `package.json` `"scripts"`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run start:dev",
    "dev:docker": "npm run docker:debug:start:local",
    "build": "nest build",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
    "docker:build": "docker build -t my-nest-service --platform linux/amd64 .",
    "docker:start": "docker run --env-file ./.env --rm --name my-nest-service -p 9002:9002 my-nest-service",
    "docker:stop": "docker stop my-nest-service",
    "docker:debug:start": "docker run --env-file ./.env --rm --name my-nest-service -p 9002:9002 my-nest-service sleep infinity",
    "docker:debug:start:local": "docker run -v %cd%:/app --env-file ./.env --rm --name my-nest-service -p 9002:9002 my-nest-service sleep infinity",
    "docker:debug:enter": "docker exec -it my-nest-service sh"
  }
```

## Explanation

So, what is happening above is that we have commands to build the app `build`, start development or prod `start:dev` `start:prod`, start and stop docker `docker:start` `docker:stop`,  start docker paused `docker:debug:start`, enter-in docker `docker:debug:enter` with terminal, ..

And then a SPECIAL command `dev:docker` or `docker:debug:start:local`, which allows us to mount local repository inside Docker's `/app` folder, which (as mentioned above) is the `WORKDIR` folder where our app code is copied..

```bash
dev:docker                 # alias for docker:debug:start:local
docker:build
docker:start               # Starts the image and app from container's `dist` folder
docker:stop
docker:debug:start         # Starts image without running the app
docker:debug:start:local   # Same as above but mounts local filesystem
docker:debug:enter         # Allows us to connect terminal inside running container
```

## Debugging inside Docker

1. `dev:docker` - Start docker container in paused state (`pause infinity`) and mounted local repo
2. `docker:debug:enter` - This allows us to get inside the container with a terminal
3. `npm run dev` We can then run the app manually from inside docker
4. Use debugging tools, connect remotely with VSCode, etc. etc.

Follows actual excerpt from our `README.md`:

---

### Development inside Docker

Useful for **debugging** docker but also for platform agnostic **development**. When on deployed environment, the image itself is set to run `npm run start:prod` (see *Dockerfile* `CMD`). All commands prefixed with `docker:` in *package.json* are never used and are there to ease control of docker in local environment.

```bash
dev:docker                 # alias for docker:debug:start:local
docker:build
docker:start               # Starts the image and app from container's `dist` folder
docker:stop
docker:debug:start         # Starts image without running the app
docker:debug:start:local   # Same as above but mounts local filesystem
docker:debug:enter         # Allows us to connect terminal inside running container
```

*PS: For local development inside docker use trio `dev:docker`, `docker:debug:enter`, `npm run dev`. Read below.*

1. Build the image

   ```bash
   npm run docker:build
   ```
2. Start the container with `sleep`
   *`sleep` pauses the container before running the application, which allows us to inspect it even in case of a terminating error.*
   There are two options:

   a) Run the complete package *built* **within the container**. This runs the code from `dist` folder (see *Dockerfile* `CMD` command).

   ```bash
   npm run docker:debug:start
   npm run start:prod # then inside docker (see step 3a)
   ```

   b) Or run with **mounted local repo**. This will completely overwrite the container's `/app` directory with your local repo's content, every change to your repo will reflect inside docker.
   **Note `%var%` is windows syntax, use `$var` on unix.*

   ```bash
   npm run docker:debug:start:local
   npm run dev # then inside docker (see step 3b)
   ```
3. Connect into the container
   Launch this command from a second terminal.

   ```bash
   docker:debug:enter
   ```

   Then, inside the container you can
   a) start the built production code from `dist`. This is the same command docker uses in Dockerfile `CMD`.

   ```bash
   npm run start:prod
   ```

   b) start from `src`. *(When using `docker:debug:start:local`.)*

   ```bash
   npm run dev
   ```

   At this point, you can run any command, since you have your full local repository linked.
4. Open app in browser http://localhost:9002/api/v1/ and do your thing.
5. Stop the container

   ```bash
   docker:stop
   ```

   Tip: You can check running containers.

   ```bash
   docker ps
   ```
6. Start the app in normal way to verify that everything works and test in browser on http://localhost:9002/api/v1/.
   *PS: You might need to rebuild your image 1).*

   ```bash
   # run prod in docker
   npm run docker:start

   # runs prod without docker
   npm run start:prod
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can, i needed to add single package to existing docker for my Python app to work and didnt want to wait for build time.

```
docker run container_name tail -f /dev/null
```

Then get in via

```
docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh
```

Ref:https://levelup.gitconnected.com/keep-docker-container-running-for-debugging-fc2dfa39472c